# How do i add gradient in tab.activeBorder in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio

How do i add color gradient in tab.activeBorderTop in  workbench.colorCustomizations in vs code ?
Is it even possible ?
Is there a way to change its height to increase or decrease the thickness of the tab.activeBorderTop ?

Want something like this [check style.css tab border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQzCP.jpg)